MSSQL query hung when ran through .NET/IIS but successfully runs in SSMS
When I manually run query directly in SSMS, it successfully runs (in 10-20sec). When the query is initiated through the .NET/IIS web application, it hangs pretty much indefinitely, and ends up locking other queries. I ended up killing after waiting 20 minutes.
What are factors that would cause a query to hang when applied through .NET/IIS application?
It has some large table joins in it, but again it runs fairly well in SSMS, so I would expect close to the same time on the .NET web application. Any ideas?
Thank you!

What are factors that would cause a query to hang
The Isolation Level. You don't specify what you are using for the query. Some ORMs may have a restrictive level such as Serializable. The default is Read Committed.

you seem to be asking the wrong question.  would you rather know how to find the cause of this query not finishing instead of the ways to cause a query not too finish?

Queries from SSMS and a web app on IIS are running under different user accounts (your own account in the former, and the application pool identity in the latter). So, did you configure the database server to match such differences?

Are you actually running the exact same query, or just a similar one?
The value of even a single parameter can have a significant impact on the query performance.
Also, as Greg Askew said, check the isolation level; if that's different when running in IIS and when running in SSMS, you could end up with a race condition or even a deadlock.

I'm highly confident the query is exactly the same. Regarding isolation level, please forgive my ignorance. Where is the isolation level defined? Is this something specified directly in the query used in .NET code, or something more general, applied in SQL server?

The isolation level of a query is defined client-side; but if you are not doing it explicitly in the query or code, it could also be implicitly set by the library (or framework) your application is using to access the database.

Also, race conditions and deadlocks are highly dependent on how many queries are accessing the same data at the same time; if you manually run a single query in SSMS you will never encounter them, but if you have a race condition in your code it will only happen when it's called multiple times in parallel.

Also (again), your query can get deadlocked on a resource used by a different query in your application, which is accessing the same data at the same time; if this is the case, manually running a single query won't cause a deadlock: only running the whole application will.

Race conditions and deadlocks are notoriously hard do debug; see if this can help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-deadlocks-guide?view=sql-server-ver16.

Very helpful insights Massimo. Thank you so much. Based off your input and what I was seeing, I think it was deadlocking on two similar queries hitting at the same time through the application. Thanks again to you/all, & God bless! :)

I recommend to check the app pool performance because I seen in the past request that fail if they take too long or use too much memory. It's a limitation SSMS don't have. Usually a fail there will be shown on your app backend, but we are lacking details on how you handle your error checkings
If such please check those settings; I paste some generic recommended settings.
Queue Length    2000 (up from default of 1000)
Idle Time-out (minutes) 0 (down from the default of 20)
Ping Enabled    False (from default of True)
Private Memory Limit (KB)   0 (unlimited, up from the default of 1,843,200 KB)
Regular Time Interval (minutes) 0 (to prevent a recycle, and modified from the default of 1740)

This has nothing to do with the performance of a SQL query against a database, which seems to get stuck in the DBMS itself.

@Massimo I agree, but I point to the app pool as I seen in the past high usage of memory for a query that was making the query never finish. (aka like a WSUS with a big DB, and the display never finish to display as the limititation of the IIS app maked the request never finish)
